# Output logging in Java

Tags: java

I'm currently working on applying genetic algorithms to a particular application, and the issue is that there is a large amount of data that I need to analyze, graph and simply, tabulate. Upto this point I have been using csv files, but they have been kind of limited as I still have to generate charts manually, and its an issue when this needs to be done on over 100 documents.

Are there any other options for output logging in Java, for analysis other than CSV files? Any link to any API of any kind would also be useful.

P.S: (The question seems common enough to have been asked already, but I couldn't find it.) I'm not asking about how to log data in Java, or how to redirect it to a file, but if there are any existing ways to easily tabulate and graph large amounts of output.

The kind of data I'm working with involves a lot of numerical data, specifically the attributes of different generations and different organisms inside those generations. I'm trying to find and interpret trends within the numerical data which would mean that I need to generate separate graphs for different populations or test runs, and also find representative values for each file and graph those against specific test run conditions.

Also, there is a time parameter which references the speed of the algorithm. Which methods let me log output without letting the post-processing and disk access affect my test runs? Is it possible?

Comment: Much depends on what kind of data you are working on and from where it's pulled; Java aside, are you using a RDBMDS? If not, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to write out an Excel spreadsheet directly.  You can also have it start with a spreadsheet already containing macros and whatever else you need to display your information.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something that didn't have much of a learning curve, this comes closest.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of choices in exporting reports / data. There is an open source project call JasperReport that can do charts, PDF, XML, CSV, plain text exporting. But it is an involved process, but does offer Java API to accomplish that task.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing table into a database, like MySQL?

Using such, you can search your data by better means than in a text file.

Have a look here: http://www.vogella.de/articles/MySQLJava/article.html

On linux, you also have the possibility to stay using your csv files and then generate plots using gnuplot scipts.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to be saving the data to a database and then using Jasper Reports to build a report containing the graphs and whatever else you need using the data that you stored in the database instead of trying to use excel. Jasper is fairly easy to use and you can have your java application generate the report for you after the data has been stored in the database.